# C++ library for network communication between laptop/device without router

Tags: c++, windows, networking, tcp, arduino

**Background**

For my project, I'm attempting to control an AUV using an Arduino mega with an ethernet shield that receives instruction from a laptop (running Windows). The server side (laptop) will be written in C++.

Since there'll only be a one to one network using TCP/IP, I am trying to avoid the use of routers in order to simplify the hardware. I found out that you could do a direct connection between two devices (with auto-MDIX).

**Therefore...**

I have briefly looked into Boost:asio but I think it's probably an overkill (because I won't need to consider multiple clients etc) crossover for what I'm trying to achieve here. Am I right?

Any advice would be appreciated! Thanks.

**TL;DR:**

Looking for a C++ networking library (that works on Windows) that allows a clean, simple code to do a one-to-one TCP/IP connection.

Comment: You just need to sysadmin both ends to make the direct connection work. Then you probably still use TCP/IP as usual. From a programming point of view nothing should change.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that and therefore my question is whether there exist a simple network library for C++ that will allow me to do just a simple one-to-one TCP/IP. I'll edit to make it clearer in the question.

Comment: Standard syscalls (see `socket(2)` and `tcp(7)` man pages) provide TCP/IP to applications. Read http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ ; very probably installing Linux on the controlling laptop would help you

Comment: Ahh, I forgot to mention that the program will run in Windows. Thanks all the same.

Comment: Then, install Linux on the laptop. It would be a lot easier.

Comment: winsock and unix/linux sockets are almost identical, just use winsock on windows or sockets on linux/unix.  A router has nothing to do with any of this.  Do you need the overhead/complication of tcp?  why not udp?

Comment: I'm a linux fan too, but unfortunately windows is one of the requirements of the project.

Comment: @dwelch I was under the impression that tcp is easier to implement, but thanks I'll look into it!

Comment: tcp is streaming, udp is packet. Udp, IF, it arrives arrives in the same size and shape (not necessarily in the same order).  tcp will arrive but can be broken up into smaller packets so you have to treat it like a serial stream not complete packets.  (even on a point to point link). I find udp much easier for this type of work, I usually do host based request and target response, half duplex, and put in a retry if it doesnt reply.  Of course I often make my own udp/ip stack from scratch as well...If you are asking questions like this you should use an existing stack for the arduino

Comment: right, I can see how udp fits my control model better since each and every command is separate and the order is irrelevant. for a local network (50m of Ethernet) I don't really need to worry about packet loss do I?
also, when you say stack do you mean like a command queue?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to set-up your arduino as a web server. See this [example sektch](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebServer) for the details.

On your Windows box use a [web client library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342493/c-web-services-client-library).

This way you can test the arduino even without your client software using your browser.